# How to show selected report pages in rdlc Reportviewer?

Tags: c#, report, report-viewer2010

I am having s group box of Radio buttons. having options like

1.) Page 1 & 2

2.) Page 3 to 6

3.) Page 7

4.) All

and on the basis of this selection I want to show my Report in the reportviewer. I am trying to search stuff on it, but didn't found any thing. My report is having one main report with seven sub-reports. Any idea or code snippet will be helpful.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest either one of two options:

1. Generate four different reports (ie. .rdlc files), one of each one of your options, including the corresponding sub-reports.
2. Have a single report and pass the option as a parameter through `SetParameters` and then dynamically exclude reports based by checking the option within your report.

I'd personally go with the first one since it will allow you more flexibility. Since each one of your sub-reports also goes in a different .rdlc, their maintenance shouldn't be a hassle and duplicity should be minor.

Comment: Nyc I went for Option 1 and it worked like magic :-) thank you.